# .htacess file is giving 500 internal server error

Tags: .htaccess, internal-server-error

Guys I am working on a project and using following .htaccess code on local server and its giving me 500 internal error
I tried modifying the code but still not able to find a solution
as I have commented the lines but still no result

```
# Comment the 2 lines below if the server returns 500 errors!
# Options -Indexes
# Options +FollowSymLinks

#Uncomment following lines if you want to use image caching!
#<IfModule mod_expires.c>
#  ExpiresActive On
#  ExpiresDefault A1209600
#  ExpiresByType text/html A1
#</IfModule>

# Uncomment following lines if Apache doesnt support MultiViews!
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Uncomment the 2 lines below if you are using www.domain.com
    # as the baseurl for the site and users access your site 
    # via domain.com (THIS IS REQUIRED FOR JQUERY TO WORK)

    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301] 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* loader.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

# Edit below lines and set to
# ErrorDocument CODE /RELATIVE/error.php
# If the script is installed in the default document
# root then relative is null.
#ErrorDocument 401 /error.php
#ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
#ErrorDocument 404 /error.php

AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
Substitute "s|</body>| <script type=\"text/javascript\">     var loc = ((\"https:\" == document.location.protocol) ? \"https://analytics.\" : \"http://analytics.\");     document.write(unescape(\"%3Cscript src='\" + loc + \"sitewit.com/v3/931271415/sw.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E\")); </script>   </body>|ni"
```

Comment: Check your Apache error.log to see what is the reason of 500 error

Answer (score 0):

You are re-writing the whole URI. So

```
http://example.com/test
```

becomes

```
loader.php
```